# "Unable to open database file" error when trying to load Doctrine Data Fixtures in Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, behat

I'm using `pdo_mysql` for prod, stag and dev environments and `pdo_sqlite` for test environment. The problem is that loading Doctrine Data Fixtures generates `unable to open database file` error as shown below. I assigned the permissions to cache folder as defined in [symfony website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup) and also tried with 777 but no luck.

I'm on MAC OS Yosemite and sqlite3 is enabled in PHP.

```
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, dblib, pgsql
SQLite3 module version  0.7-dev
SQLite Library  3.8.8.3
```

**This command creates the database successfully:**

```
MBP:football bc$ php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
Updating database schema...
Database schema updated successfully! "9" queries were executed
```

**This command fails:**

```
MBP:football bc$ php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction --no-debug --env=test

  [PDOException]                                     
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file
```

**config_test.yml** (both configs won't work)

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_sqlite
        path: %kernel.cache_dir%/default.db
        charset: UTF8

#doctrine:
#    dbal:
#        default_connection: default
#
#        connections:
#            default:
#                driver:  pdo_sqlite
#                path:    %kernel.cache_dir%/default.db
#                charset: utf8
```

**config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Settings/steps above work fine in Ubuntu so this is a MAC OS related issue. Mac users, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in Symfony [website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup), if you run into a kind of permissions issue, Mac users should use specific permissions on `app/cache` folder by running commands below:

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps aux | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo chmod +a "$HTTPDUSER allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
$ sudo chmod +a "`whoami` allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

Actually this is what causes the problem so to solve this issue run:

```
rm -Rf app/cache/test/*
```

and do not assign any permissions to `cache/test` folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by creating a parent directory for database file: 
    `database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3`, so I've created 'data' directory. And, of course, make shure that all folders a writable by Doctrine. Hope it helps!